# PHP login system / sessions isn't working the first time

Tags: php, session, authentication

Its a little tough to diagnosis the problem here so sorry if my description is a little vague.  I have a pretty standard login system and its working fine for the most part.  I noticed a problem today though when I restarted my browser ... it won't log me in on admin1.php unless I visit admin2.php first and navigate back to admin1.php.

After that everything works perfectly. I can logout and log back in just fine.

Here are the two files I have ...

**admin1.php**

```
<style>
#form_contain {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 100px 0 0 !important;
}

label {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type='text'], input[type="password"] {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell !important;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 260px !important;
}
</style>

<?php
session_start();
include "lib/head.php";

function protect($string)
{
 $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 return $string;
} 

$user = $_SESSION['username']; 

if(!$_POST['submit'])
{
    if ($_SESSION['logged'] == true) {
        include_once("admin_main.php");
        }
    else {

?>

<div id="form_contain">
    <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="16">
        <br>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="16">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn">
    </form>
    <p id="alert"></p>  
</div>


<?php
    }
}
else
{
  $user = protect($_POST['username']);
  $pass = protect($_POST['password']);

if($user && $pass)
{
    $sql="SELECT id,username FROM catalog_users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); // mysql_fetch_assoc gets the value for each field in the row
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id']; //creates the first session var
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; // second session var
            $_SESSION['logged'] = true;

            echo '
                <script language="javascript">
                    window.location = "admin1.php";
                </script>";

            ';

        }
        else
       {
            echo '
                <script language="javascript">
                    window.location="admin_wrong.php";    
                </script>
            ';
        }   
}
else
{           
    echo '
        <script language="javascript">
            window.location="admin_wrong.php";    
        </script>
    ';
}
}
?>
```

**admin2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('lib/head.php');


if (isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'] == true) {
    echo "
        This is a secured page, welcome <b>".$_SESSION['username']."</b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href='admin1.php'>Back</a>
        <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>

        ";
    }
else {
    echo "<b>Sorry, you cannot access this page</b>";
}   


?>
```

**Update:** The CSS prior to the `<?php session_start()` at top of my code was causing the problem

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: also. `<script language="javascript">` <- this is not how we add JS to the web page

Comment: I'm still new to the server-side stuff.  I'll have to read up on this some more, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because your log in code comes **after** your html, so it appears like you are not logged in even though the script does log you in at the end of the script.

Typically you would want to keep your PHP and HTML as separate as possible (in different files), and do all of your PHP business logic first, then output all the HTML.

Comment: My first crack at moving the PHP above the HTML didn't fix it.  Like I told @tereško, I'm a little new to PHP so I'm sure my code isn't 100% best practices.  Thanks for your help, I'll play around with this some more and see if I can get it working.  I'll let you know.

Comment: @RyanGrush Also, if you want to redirect using PHP, use `header("Location: blah")`, but be sure to put this before you have output anything to the browser, even white space, as headers must be sent before anything else.

Comment: I don't think its an issue of how its being redirected right?  I tried replacing the JS redirect with a <META HTTP-EQUIV=""> but that didn't help.  Maybe I need to just find another login system solution, I'm kind of stumped here.

Comment: @RyanGrush no the problem is, as I originally stated, that your log in code does not happen until after your HTML is already outputted.

Comment: Wow, I spoke too soon. I had some CSS before the <?php session_start(); that I didn't include in my first post that was causing the problem.  Thanks for your patience :) ... it always the little things.